# perl use once warning with file handle

Tags: perl, warnings

Why do I get the warning `Name "main::USER_INPUT" used only once: possible typo` when I run the following script?...

```
my $success_open = open USER_INPUT , '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filehandle;

if(!$success_open)
{
    die "Failed to open: $filehandle. $!";
}

while(<USER_INPUT>)
{
    push @storage, $_;
}

close USER_INPUT;
```

Despite the warning, the script runs fine.  It seems that I use `USER_INPUT` three times: once when I open it as a filehandle, once when I read from it, and once when I close it.  Do `open` and `close` not count as usage of USER_INPUT?  My guess is that `warnings` should count them.  If it doesn't count them, then why?

I read several web pages about the `once` warning, and they give solutions to suppress the warning, but they do not seem to give enough information to understand why/how `once` occurs for my case:

- https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html
- [Getting "... used only once: possible typo" warning when aliasing subroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543925/getting-used-only-once-possible-typo-warning-when-aliasing-subroutines)
- ["name used only once" warning while using List::Util::reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521413/name-used-only-once-warning-while-using-listutilreduce)
- https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1021888
- https://perlmaven.com/name-used-only-once-possible-typo

How/Where can I find more info about how the `once` warning works?  Is there a URL, Book, file, etc.?  Maybe the code for `once` is in my Perl installation somewhere, but I do not know where.  I've also skimmed through the following books (including their indices) and did not find any detailed info about `once`:

- Learning Perl
- Intermediate Perl
- Mastering Perl
- Programming Perl
- Perl Cookbook

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce the error you claim it does. It produces `Name "main::storage" used only once: possible typo at a.pl line 10.` and `@storage` is indeed used only once.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. And don't use global vars for file handles; instead, use `open my $USER_INPUT, ...`, etc.

Comment: Don't use bareword filehandles. Use lexical filehandles instead.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958624/perl-name-mainin-used-only-once-but-it-is-actually-used

Comment: If it's not a duplicate (i.e. if you aren't using `use autodie;`), please fix your question so it actually demonstrates your problem and we'll reopen the Question.

Comment: My question is a duplicate.  I was using `autodie`. The code I used in my example is a snippet of a lengthier script.  I excluded the other portions of my script (including the pragmas), because I incorrectly thought they were not pertinent.  I realized that the snippet I used was incomplete because because @ikegami pointed out the different warning it produced.  Rookie mistake I guess.  So, lesson learned: One should use scalar filehandles instead of `bareword filehandles` (aka `package filehandles`?) or else `use autodie` may trigger a bug.

Comment: One should limit the scope of variables to where they are needed, autodie or not.